# Casas decimais no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tipagem

Qual o tipo de variável eu consigo usar para gerar o máximo de casas decimais no JavaScript?

Ex.: 1.9871975109731928479128471023789182479182471209381290481284

Se for possível, lógico =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript só tem um tipo numérico, então é ele que deve usar. E claro, ele tem um máximo e é este máximo que pode usar.

É bom saber que JS usa um tipo numérico baseado em ponto flutuante binário e isto significa que não haverá exatidão numérica, se precisa disto não dá, mas pelo exposto não parece ser o caso. O máximo é o [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE).

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/MaxValue.js).

Se isto não resolver terá que fazer ou pegar uma biblioteca que crie um tipo que atenda sua necessidade.

Comment: o JS não precisa definir um tipo para a variável basta usar `var` antes, porém por dentro ela faz algum tipo de teste para definir o tipo para essa variável?

Comment: Esse seria o maior valor possível ou o maior número de casas decimais possível?

Comment: @bfavaretto como está em notação científica tanto faz ;)

Comment: Eu tentei fazer as contas pra ver se batia, mas desisti no meio rs. Mas andei lendo que a *precisão* é [por volta de 15 dígitos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), independente da  posição do ponto decimal. Então não deve importar muito quantas casas dá pra representar depois disso. Acho. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam note que eu nãi falei em variável, falei em valor, em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica as variáveis não tem tipo, mas os valores sempre tem. Nessas linguagens há uma *tag*  junto ao valor então a variável tem um tipo de acordo com seu valor e isto é testado internamente para saber o que fazer, inclusive dar erro.

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade é um pouco mais complicado, como pode ser visto tem mais de 300 casas. Isto não quer dizer que todos os números podem ser representados, mas é possível ter essa quantidade de casas. Existem os mais significativos, no caso a representação mostrou 16 e "engoliu" 308.

Answer (score 1):

Os números em JavaScript são sempre do tipo `Number`, e sempre são de ponto flutuante de 64 bits, no padrão IEEE 754:

- Mantissa/Fração: 52 bits;
- Expoente: 11 bits;
- Sinal: 1 bit;

> [O valor máximo que pode ser atingido é aproximadamente 3.4028235×10e38](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233444/max-float-represented-in-ieee-754)