# Como exibir a maior quantidade de casas decimais em javascript?

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estava fazendo uns experimentos e gostaria de calcular as 1.000 primeiras casas decimais da constante de Euler (como demonstrado nesse site http://www.profcardy.com/cardicas/constantes.php), então fiz esse programa em javascript:

```js
(function euler(){

var f;
var c = 0;
var n = 1;
var fx = 0;

while (c <= 10000){

    f = (1+(1/n));

    fx = Math.pow(f,n);

    console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE, fx);
    n++;
    c++;
}
})();
```

Ao rodar no console o último resultado foi 1.7976931348623157e+308 2.7181459404132355. Como faço para os exibir as 1.000 primeiras casas decimais como no exemplo dado no site? Pode ser em javascript ou qualquer outra linguagem.
Encontrei essa pergunta [Casas decimais no JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282194/casas-decimais-no-javascript), porém sem a resolução que necessito.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Entendendo a questão você pode considerar o seguinte:

O JS usa um tipo numérico baseado em ponto flutuante binário e isto significa que não haverá exatidão numérica. O máximo é o `Number.MAX_VALUE` (1.7976931348623157e+308). Que considera uma precisão de até 15 casas decimais exatas.

Considerando isso. Então o que você precisa é de uma biblioteca de manipulação de números decimais de precisão arbitrária. Utilize a biblioteca [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum).

Um exemplo de como ela funciona pode ser verificado aqui: [Como calcular PI com “n” casas decimais em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51625/como-calcular-pi-com-n-casas-decimais-em-javascript)